# What are the causes of a fsockopen() error?

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have two scripts that are identical but one works on my home testing server and when uploaded to my hosting provider it times out.

homedns.org/hmm/example.php (is working on my home server)

x.x.x.x/~cvxadmin/pvpgnserverscript/example.php

I'm stumped, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple possiblilities. There could be a firewall setup blocking external connections (or blocking specific ports).

Alternatively there could be something within the php configuration that has disabled the socket functionality.

Make sure you have php errors explicitily displayed on your site5 account as they might reveal why you're not able o use this function.

Comment: I made sure that all errors that happen should be reported in the php script. But that's the only error it displays. I guess I'll have to go to the site5 support forums to get this looked up by tech support...

Comment: you can try checking the php.ini configuration by using <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Try checking that there arn't any settings that would be stopping your connection. Also try a basic php script that tries a socket connection to google or yahoo (make sure it's not something on the server you're connecting to)